# I need to find the location of a value in one numpy array and use it to refer to a value in the same location of another numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, raspberry-pi

I am writing code to analyze accelerometer data on a raspberry pi. The sensor data is output to a single txt file with columns separated by \t. I imported the text file using numpy.loadtxt and unpacked it into separate arrays. I can perform things like trapz and cumtrapz on the arrays.

This data will be used in combination with another sensor that will output a specific time of an event. I want to take that time, find the closest logged time from my sensor and correspond it to values from the other arrays.

I tried using numpy.where with a specific time value that i knew was in the list and got an output of "(array([], dtype=int32),)"

Here is the code I ran. I'm sure I misused at least one thing. I am still very much a beginner in Python and coding in general...

```
import logging
import sys
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
x,y,z,t=np.loadtxt('a.txt', dtype={'names':['x','y','z','t'], 
'formats':['f4','f4','f4','f4']},unpack='true')
p = integrate.trapz(integrate.cumtrapz(x, t, initial=0), t)
ti = np.where(x==1.5670002)
print ti
print p
```

The full output from that is

```
(array([], dtype=int32),)
0.0114166
```

So I was searching x for a value from t. it is now outputting 
    (array([101]),)

How would I print that corresponding number from another array?

Comment: That's nice! Would you mind just showing what your ``x, y, z, t`` are after reading? Doesn't need to be the whole file, just the first few entries (and their shape) will suffice.

Comment: when I tell it to print t the first few values are [ 0.2712      0.28029999  0.28920001  0.29800001  0.30680001  0.3163
  0.32530001  0.3344      0.3441      0.35280001  0.36129999  0.37079999

Comment: Would it just be "print x[ti[0]]" to print the corresponding x value if ti is output as  (array([101]),)

Comment: I believe I figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
import logging
import sys
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
x,y,z,t=np.loadtxt('a.txt', dtype={'names':['x','y','z','t'], 
'formats':['f4','f4','f4','f4']},unpack='true')
p = integrate.cumtrapz(integrate.cumtrapz(x, t, initial=0), t)
t0=input("What is reference time?")
ti = np.where(t>=t0)[0][0]
if t[ti]-t0 <= t0-t[ti-1]:
    t1 = ti
else:
    t1 = ti-1

print ('closest time was {0:0.4f}\ndisplacement at that time was {1:0.4f}' .format(t[t1],p[t1]))
```

output is

```
closest time was 1.1991
displacement at that time was 0.0100
```

Seems to be working. I will have to add error messages for when the reference time is outside of a usable range. Would love some constructive criticism though. Any commands that you think would work better/faster than what I have used?